# Does installing Ubuntu 12.10 with 'Erase Win7' option deletes Windows partitions?

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, system-installation, windows, data-recovery

I had Win 7 in `C:\` and other data in `F:\ G:\ H:\` partitions. Installed Ubuntu 12.10 with option `Erase win7 and install Ubuntu` and checked LVM option. After installing Ubuntu I'm not able to see `F:\ G:\ H:\` partitions.

Does this mean I lost all data on `F:\ G:\ H:\` or is there any way to recover?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You **deleted** windows, all your data is lost. Time to pull out your backup USB. Also F:\ G:\ H:\ and drive labels like that are merely abstractions created by windows, (they don't exist in other OS'es) as Ubuntu may have left some of these partitions alone and only removed the main windows partition, they may still exist, open up the file manager and look in the side bar for anything without a name. (IE something that has just defaulted to saying the file system size). Also, no offence meant, but what else did you think "erase windows 7" meant?

Comment: Is there any way to recover my data that I had previosly

Comment: @PraveenMuthusamy There are some data recovery methods, however I don't know if they work for deleted partitions, as most of the bytes on the disk will have been overwritten by your Ubuntu partition. Please say you made a backup before installing!

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . Actually I assumed "erase win7" will have some intelligence to use the partition where the windows resides and leave other partitions without touching.

Comment: You're assuming that F:\, G:\ and H:\ were actual partitions. If they were created with Windows, there is a good possibility they were not, and were extended volumes or such. Also, if there were partitions you wanted to save, why didn't you back up data you needed? Anytime you are installing a new OS that may potentially change drive/partition layout, there is a small but significant chance you'll lose data, even if you tell it to leave those partitions alone.

Comment: @DrakeClarris : ya , I got it , I was somehow confused by the wordings , "Erase Windows 7"

Comment: testdisk recovered data , almost everything, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have lost them.
If you are good at linux:
 1. DO NOT USE UBUNTU YOU JUST INSTALLED! (Tmp files WILL overwrite WIN7)
 2. Make a Knoppix live CD/USB/DVD/whatever.
 3. Boot from it.
 4. Mount all you disks (If it didnt do it automaticaly) 
 5. Open up console and launch "testdisk". (You will find it easy to use)
 6. Copy everything that you dont wanna be forever lost to USB (BUT NOT TO HARDDRIVE!)
You wont be able to recover you WIN7 but atleast save some files (Maybe)

But if you aren't good with Linux enough (as i see) then you better bring it to service that will do this for you.

Comment: `testdisk` is also available in the Ubuntu repositories, why does the user need to get Knoppix??? A Ubuntu livecd will do also the trick without having the user to go trough another interface...

Comment: #BrunoPereira Sir, i am telling how i recovered last time. I am just sure that knoppix can do it. I dont limit you to following my instructions "EXACTLY". (I am a Debian user helping to Ubuntozoids)

Comment: @LoCoZeNozZUE Thanks, testdisk works great, recovered 100 GB of data , though I lost some files.